# Find substring from string output

Tags: string, vbscript, substring

I have a script (below) that finds the current version of Microsoft Office Installed and outputs it as a string. The string output for example would be 15.0.4771.1000. I don't care about anything past the 15. My goal is to verify that the version of Office is 15. I want to take the substring of the digts before the 1st `.` (period) and compare it to the value in questioned. How would I do this?

The script below doesn't work even with a wild card for the compared value.

```
Dim oRegistry
Dim oFSO
Dim sKey
Dim sAppExe
Dim sValue
Dim sAppVersion

Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002

Set oRegistry = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}//./root/default:StdRegProv")
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
sKey = "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths"
oRegistry.GetStringValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, sKey & "\" & sAppExe, "", sValue
MsgBox oFSO.GetFileVersion(sValue)
If oFSO.GetFileVersion(sValue)="15.*" Then
  WScript.Echo("Office 2013 is installed")
Else
  WScript.Echo("You do not have Office 2013 installed")
End If
Set oFSO = Nothing
Set oRegistry = Nothing
```

Comment: [`Split` Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0764e5w5(v=vs.84).aspx)

Comment: Does it have to be VBScript?  You could do the same thing with PowerShell, KiXtart, etc. and achieve the same goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least half a dozen ways to check a part of the string, but "wildcards" do not exist in VBScript.

One way would be `If Left(value, 3) = "15." ...`. Another one would rely on the fact that a version string uses dots as separators: `If Split(value, ".")(0) = 15 ...`.

The following uses `Split()` and cuts out the WMI; there is an easier way to read the registry in VBScript:

```
Option Explicit

Dim Shell, FSO, path, version
Set Shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

path = TryRegRead("HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\excel.exe\")
If FSO.FileExists(path) Then version = FSO.GetFileVersion(path)

If version = "" Then
    WScript.Echo "You do not have Office installed at all"
ElseIf Split(version, ".")(0) = 15 Then
    WScript.Echo "You have Office 2013 installed"
Else
    WScript.Echo "You have a different version of Office (" + version + ")"
End If

Function TryRegRead(key)
    On Error Resume Next
    TryRegRead = Shell.RegRead(key)
End Function
```

Notes

- get into the habit of using `Option Explicit` in every script
- don't bother setting stuff to `Nothing`, it really is not worth it
- The backslash at the end of the path is required, it makes `Shell.RegRead()` return the default value for that key.
- I'm pretty sure reading iterating the children of `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` and reading the Office version from there is a safer way of finding that information, compared to relying on the App Path for a single executable from the Office package.

Comment: The fact you bother to explain it rather then just posting code get's my vote.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do this. For instance you could split the string at dots and take the first field of the resulting array:

```
version = oFSO.GetFileVersion(sValue)
majorVersion = Split(version, ".")(0)
```

Other options would be to extract the substring up to the first dot with string functions:

```
version = oFSO.GetFileVersion(sValue)
majorVersion = Left(version, InStr(version, "."))
```

or with a regular expression:

```
Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "^(\d+)\..*"

version = oFSO.GetFileVersion(sValue)
majorVersion = re.Replace(version, "$1")
```