# Find a specific substring within a string VBScript

Tags: vbscript

```
Dim string1 = "631;27;73"
Dim string2 = "31"
```

`InStr(string1, string2)` returns 2 since 31 is a subset of `string1`.
For my current scenario, I want to match the whole number. `string2 = 31` is not a matching number in `string1` and hence I want to return a zero and append 31 to `string1`.

Comment: I see 2 ways you could approach this: a) split `string1` at semicolons and compare the substrings with `string2` in a loop, or b) use a regular expression where you match on word boundaries (`\b`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find substring from string output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34051999/find-substring-from-string-output)

Answer (score 2):

You can split your number list into an array and compare each number:

```
Function NumberExists(p_sNumber, p_sList)
    Dim arrValues
    Dim iCounter

    arrValues = Split(p_sList, ";")

    For iCounter = 0 To UBound(arrValues)
        If p_sNumber = arrValues(iCounter) Then
            ' Number is found
            NumberExists = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next

    NumberExists = False

End Function
```

In your scenario, you can use the function like this:

```
Dim string1
Dim string2

string1 = "631;27;73"
string2 = "31"

MsgBox NumberExists(string2, string1)
```

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, please accept the answer by clicking on gray check mark symbol on the left of an answer. A question with no accepted answer is rated as a not answered question even if there are good answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Do This Code Get Better Result

```
Dim string1
Dim string2
Dim vCount

string1 = "631;27;73"
string2 = "632"
vCount = 1

vSplit = Split(string1, ";")

For each value1 in vSplit

If value1 = string2 And vCount = 1 Then
Result = "Number Exist"
vCount = vCount+1
ElseIf  vCount = 1 Then
Result = "Number Not Exist"
End If 

Next

MsgBox(Result)
```